# 6.27 LAB: Even/odd values in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Working on a lab problem:

> Write a program that reads a list of integers, and outputs whether the list contains all even numbers, odd numbers, or neither. The input begins with an integer indicating the number of integers that follow.

This is the code I have so far:

```py
def input_values(new_list):
    new_list = []
    n = int(input('Enter number of values: '))
    for i in range(n):
        new_list.append(int(input('Enter values: ')))
    def is_list_even(new_list):
        for i in range(len(new_list)):
            if new_list[i]%2!=0:
                return False
            return True
    def is_list_odd(new_list):
        for i in range(len(new_list)):
            if new_list[i]%2==0:
                return False
            return True
    num=input_values()
    if is_list_even(num)==True:
        print('all even')
    elif is_list_odd(num)==True:
        print('all odd')
    else:
        print('not even or odd')
```

I keep getting syntax errors saying

> 'function' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

or

> new_list not defined

and I don't know how to fix it, I've tried putting `str()` in front of all the `new_list`'s and it still wouldn't fix it. As for the "not defined" I don't even know where to start for fixing that one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Is the code in the question indented exactly as the code that causes the problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After few changes it seems to work. Read carefuly

```
def lab_627():
    new_list = []
    n = int(input('Enter number of values: '))
    for i in range(n):
        new_list.append(int(input('Enter values: ')))

    def is_list_even():
        for i in range(len(new_list)):
            if new_list[i] % 2 != 0:
                return False
        return True

    def is_list_odd():
        for i in range(len(new_list)):
            if new_list[i] % 2 == 0:
                return False
        return True

    if is_list_even():
        print('all even')
    elif is_list_odd():
        print('all odd')
    else:
        print('not even or odd')


lab_627()
```

Comment: So, maybe I missed something looking it over, but it looks like the only difference between this one and mine was instead of "num=input_values()" you had "lab_627()". I'm not exactly clear on what difference that makes, but it works so I'm not complaining. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 0):

On the line which says:
`num = input_values()`
The reason you would get an error there is because there isn't a positional argument, you should remove the 'new_list' in
`def input_values(new_list):`

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_list_even(my_list):
        for i in range(len(my_list)):
            if my_list[i] % 2 != 0:
                return False
        return True
        
def is_list_odd(my_list):
        for i in range(len(my_list)):
            if my_list[i] % 2 == 0:
                return False
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_list = []
    n = int(input())
    for i in range(n):
        my_list.append(int(input()))
        
        
    if is_list_even(my_list):
        print('all even')
    elif is_list_odd(my_list):
        print('all odd')
    else:
        print('not even or odd')
```

Answer (score -1):

here is a clean easily readable way to do that

```
def isEven(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            return False
    return True

def isOdd(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            return False
    return True
            
def listClassification(lst):
    if isEven(lst):
        print("list is even")
    elif isOdd(lst):
        print("list is odd")
    else:
        print("list is mixed")

listClassification([1,3,5,7])
listClassification([2,4,6,8])
listClassification([1,2,3,4])
```

output:

```
list is odd
list is even
list is mixed
```